# QGraphicsItem repaint

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, repaint, qgraphicsitem

I want to change text color inside a rectangle periodically.
Here is my trial:

```
 TrainIdBox::TrainIdBox()
 {
   boxRect = QRectF(0,0,40,15);
   testPen = QPen(Qt:red);
   i=0;
   startTimer(500);
 }

QRectF TrainIdBox::boundingRect() const
{
 return boxRect;
}

void TrainIdBox::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,   QWidget *widget)
{
  Q_UNUSED(widget);
  Q_UNUSED(option);

  painter->setPen(QPen(drawingColor,2));
  painter->drawRect(boxRect);
  painter->setPen(testPen);
  painter->drawText(boxRect,Qt::AlignCenter,"TEST");

 }
 void TrainIdBox::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *te)
 {
  testPen = i % 2 == 0 ? QPen(Qt::green) : QPen(Qt::yellow);
  i++;
  update(boxRect);
 }
```

This code does not working properly.
What is wrong?

Comment: I assume TrainIdBox inherits from QGraphicsItem, at least somewhere along the line?  If not, what does it inherit from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inherit from QGraphicsObject ... I give here an example:

Declare:

```
 class Text : public QGraphicsObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Text(QGraphicsItem * parent = 0);
        void paint ( QPainter * painter,
                     const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget  );
        QRectF boundingRect() const ;
        void timerEvent ( QTimerEvent * event );

    protected:
        QGraphicsTextItem * item;
        int time;
    };
```

implementation:

```
Text::Text(QGraphicsItem * parent)
    :QGraphicsObject(parent)
{
    item = new QGraphicsTextItem(this);
    item->setPlainText("hello world");

    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);    
    time  = 1000;
    startTimer(time);
}

void Text::paint ( QPainter * painter,
                   const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget  )
{
    item->paint(painter,option,widget);    
}

QRectF Text::boundingRect() const
{
    return item->boundingRect();
}

void Text::timerEvent ( QTimerEvent * event )
{
    QString timepass = "Time :" + QString::number(time / 1000) + " seconds";
    time = time + 1000;
    qDebug() <<  timepass;
}
```

good luck

Answer (score 3):

QGraphicsItem is not derived from QObject and hence does not have an event queue, which is needed to handle timer events. Try using [QGraphicsObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html) or multiple inheritance of QGraphicsItem and QObject (which is exactly what QGraphicsObject does).

Answer (score 0):

Check if Timer was properly initialized, it shouldn't return 0.

Try also changing color of brush used to paint.

I check your code when I get some free time in home, but that won't be before Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

As the base point, you could watch [Wiggly Example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/widgets-wiggly.html) and find some errors in you code yourself, what is much better. For Qt, in my opinion, it's a good practice to look sometimes in **Examples and Demos** application.

Good luck!